# Transposing matrix is not outputting correctly

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to transpose a 5x4 matrix to a 4x5 matrix but the output does not match and I don't know where the issue is in my logic. Also having issues simply printing the initial matrix. I think the issue may lie in how I am accessing each value in the matrix?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int temp;
    int array[5][4] = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {9,10,11,12}, {13,14,15,16}, {17,18,19,20}};

    for(i=0; i<4; i++);
    {
        for(j=0; j<5; j++);
        {
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {   
        for(j=0; j<5; j++)
        {                            
            temp=array[i][j];
            array[i][j]=array[j][i];                
            array[j][i]=temp;
            printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
0                                                                                           
1 5 9 13 17                                                                                 
5 6 10 14 18                                                                                
9 10 11 15 19                                                                               
13 14 15 16 20
```

Comment: Transposing a non-square 2d matrix in place is not a simple operation.  Try transposing a 2x3 to get a 3x2 using your algorithm on a piece of paper. If you're systematic, you'll soon see what's going wrong.

Comment: @Gene yeah I realize the issue now, I re-coded the program using the initial array and a second empty array and it works fine. Thank you!